# Difficulty coding a chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

Hi I wanna coding a chart with html,css and javascript(or chartjs). but I don't know how to should code of this chart and I don't enugh time for learn :(
Can someone help me?
[I have to code this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RCeF.png)
Extra:
The numbers written in the photo are in Farsi and the meaning of the numbers is as follows:
X-axis numbers from left: 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200
Y-axis numbers from bottom to top: 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100

[The checkerboard behind the diagram is a picture that I put here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OMgi.png)
[And this is also a graph that is placed on one of the points on the graph according to the number that is entered for the input data of the x-axis and y-axis.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmgyz.png)
This chart should be dynamic. so that when each of the black hollow circles is clicked, they turn orange and the one that was selected before becomes a hollow black circle and the y-axis number is placed next to the orange circle
Please help me, I'm a newbie and I'm afraid I'll be fired if I can't deliver on time :(

I tried this code, but I could not code the design in the picture

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Break Linear Graph</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<input type="number" id="x" value="10">
<input type="number" id="y" value="10">
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: "line",
data: {
labels: ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"],
datasets: [{
label: "Break Linear",
data: Array.from(Array(10), function(_, i) {
var xValue = i * x / 10;
var yValue = i * y / 10;
return Math.min(xValue, yValue);
}),
borderColor: "#000",
backgroundColor: "#ccc"
}]
},
options: {
scales: {
yAxes: [{
ticks: {
beginAtZero: true
},
min: 0,
max: 10
}],
xAxes: [{
ticks: {
beginAtZero: true
},
min: 0,
max: 10
}],
breaks: [{
position: 5,
direction: "up"
}]
}
}
});
var xInput = document.getElementById("x");
var yInput = document.getElementById("y");
xInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
var x = parseInt(xInput.value);
var y = parseInt(yInput.value);
myChart.data.datasets[0].data = Array.from(Array(10), function(_, i) {
var xValue = i * x / 10;
var yValue = i * y / 10;
return Math.min(xValue, yValue);
});
myChart.update();
});
yInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
var x = parseInt(xInput.value);
var y = parseInt(yInput.value);
myChart.data.datasets[0].data = Array.from(Array(10), function(_, i) {
var xValue = i * x / 10;
var yValue = i * y / 10;
return Math.min(xValue, yValue);
});
myChart.update();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Neither a kind nor a constructive comment @MarkSchultheiss.

Comment: I have time to learn in the future, but I have time now to master chart coding.
-@Mark Schultheiss

Comment: First of all, go to Chart.js 4. 2.94. is not maintained. Another hint. Start from sample (in doc site), they are all vanilla JS therefore a good starting point, I guess https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/line.html. To draw the dashed line, we could use a specific plugin, chartjs-plugin-annotation.

Comment: This is a good starting point I guess. https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/mdQXQqM